# Adding labels to min and max of a range type input control?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, windows-store-apps

My code:

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="12" step="4" />
```

I am building a Windows Store App and would like to indicate min and max in terms of labels as well. 0 being fast and 12 being slow.

Comment: What's your problem?  What did you try? What results did you get? (And consider creating a jsFiddle example)

Comment: @broofa, I am simply trying to display a range control using the above code. I want to label my min and max values.

Comment: Are you just trying to add a label above the range control, with "0" on the left and "12" on the right?

Comment: Yes but I want the labels under the bar.

Answer (score 2):

This should work reasonably well on modern browsers ([see jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aNXET/)):

```
0 <input type="range" min="0" max="12" step="4" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle" /> 12
```